# Использование Comparator::thenComparing в качестве аргумента метода, принимающего BinaryOperator<Comparator<T>>

Tags: java, java-stream, лямбда-выражение

```
public  int compare(T t1, T t2){

        return Arrays.stream(comparators).reduce((ttt1,ttt2)->0,Comparator::thenComparing).compare(t1,t2);
    }
```

Не могу понять, почему передаем ссылку на этот метод?

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        int res = compare(c1, c2);
        return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
    };
}
```

Хотя, `public interface BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T>`
в методе reduce реализует метод:`R apply(T t, U u);`
И ссылка на метод Comparator::thenComparing по идее никак не может заменить лямбда-выражение, так как метод, на который идет ссылка, должен совпадать по параметрам и результату с методом функционального интерфейса.

P.S. Новичек в Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код (с некоторыми оговорками) эквивалентен следующему:

```java
final Comparator<T> identity = new Comparator<T>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(T ttt1, T ttt2) {
        return 0;
    }
};

final BinaryOperator<Comparator<T>> accumulator = new BinaryOperator<Comparator<T>>() {
    @Override
    public Comparator<T> apply(Comparator<T> comparator1, Comparator<T> comparator2) {
        return comparator1.thenComparing(comparator2);
    }
};

return Arrays.stream(comparators).reduce(identity, accumulator).compare(t1,t2);
```

`Comparator::thenComparing` принимает в качестве аргументов два (если считать `this`) компаратора, и компаратор же возвращает, т.е. полностью подходит для того, чтобы на его основе был сконструирован анонимный объект, реализующий `BinaryOperator<Comparator<T>>`

Comment: Спасибо, совсем забыл про передачу ссылки в метод.

Comment: @Артем ссылок на метод, как например в c++, в java нет. `Comparator::thenComparing` это просто более короткий вариант записи лямбды `(a, b) -> a.thenComparing(b)`